# JQuery nested $.each loop not executing in order?

Tags: jquery

Basically I want to loops through all the inputs that has a "data-id" attribute and with a matching ItemID, then insert them into the database in order. Unfortunately they're not being inserted into the database in the correct order.

Here is my html:

```
<input id="control01" data-ItemId="11" value="xxx">
<input id="control02" data-ItemId="11" value="xxx">
<input id="control03" data-ItemId="12" value="xxx">
<input id="control04" data-ItemId="12" value="xxx">
<input id="control05" data-ItemId="12" value="xxx">
<input id="control06" data-ItemId="13" value="xxx">
<input id="control07" data-ItemId="13" value="xxx">
<input id="control08" data-ItemId="13" value="xxx">
<input id="control09" data-ItemId="14" value="xxx">    
<input id="control10" data-ItemId="14" value="xxx">
<input id="control11" data-ItemId="14" value="xxx">
```

Here's my code:

```
var ItemIDs = [12,13,14]; //Here's the given ID we're looking for
$.each(ItemIDs, function (index, value) {
        //alert(value); If I add an alert here it'll be inserted in the correct order
        $(":input[data-id='" + value + "']").each(function (index2, value2) {
        //Code to insert its value into SQL database;
        //PageMethods.AddItemToDB(ItemID);
       });   
    });
```

**I want the result in the database to be:**

AutoID        ItemID
1                 12
2                 12
3                 12
4                 13
5                 13
6                 13
7                 14
8                 14
9                 14

**But here's what I'm getting:**

AutoID        ItemID
1                 12
2                 12
3                 13
4                 14
5                 14
6                 13
7                 14
8                 12
9                 13

I have no clue why the order is so random. I tried adding an alert inside each loop, which to my surprise actually fixed the problem, otherwise it'll just be in random order. What am I doing wrong here? I'll greatly appreciate any help or suggestion!

Comment: How are you inserting them in the database? If you're calling an asynchronous function, they may not be executed in order.

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using?  Because calling `$.each` on `"12 13 14"` is only going to iterate once, since that's not an array.  Should be `[12, 13, 14]`

Comment: Sorry edited @grimmdude

Comment: I'm calling a [Webmethod] in C# code behind to connect to my database then inserting the record. @Barmar

Comment: The issue is that calling webmethods in Javascript is asynchronous. There's no guarantee that they'll be executed in the same order that you call them.

Comment: I think there may be a delay on your database insert script... Which may not always be equal for each iterations. You should build an array result and proceed to the database insert only once.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$.each(ItemIDs, ...)`?

Comment: And you don't need to use `IDs[index]`, just use `value`.

Comment: Thanks, corrected @Barmar

Comment: Funny thing is that when I use an alert in my code it worked as expected @Barmar

Comment: That's because the alert blocks the script, which allows the pending asynchronous call to complete before you start the next one.

Comment: If you care what order the records are insert into the database, you're doing something wrong. You should make the order inherent in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @Barmar mentioned that calling WebMethod in javascript is asynchronous, I ended up adding a new column in the table just for sorting purpose and then inserted a new index into it. It's finally working the way I wanted! Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var IDArray = [];
$("input[data-ItemId]").each(function() {
     if ($.inArray($(this).data("ItemId"), ItemIDs)) {
         IDArray.push($(this).data("ItemId"));
     }
});
```

I'm not sure how you want to add these values to the db but this code will add them to an array if they are present in that array (`ItemIDs`)